# __init__.py descends dirtree for python, but not from c++; causes "import matplotlib" error

Tags: c++, python, import, path, init

Why or how does the file `__init__.py` cause the python interpreter to search
subdirectories for a module -- and why does the interpreter not honor this
convention when invoked from C++?

Here's what I know:

Using strace on my program, I can see that the same
python2.5 interpreter is being executed for both the interactive case and the
C++ invocation.

In both cases, the PYTHONPATH directs the
search for the imported module in question (matplotlib).  This appears as a
series of open() calls, starting from the current working directory and
extending to the PYTHONPATH (here, `/opt/epd/lib/python2.5/site-packages`), and
lastly into the subdirectories, in the working case.

The full disclosure is that I am using the "Enthought" distribution and had to
place the `__init__.py` file in the `site-packages` directory and put the
`site-packages` directory in the PYTHONPATH to create the working case.

The code is below.  It seems that I may need to make a call to configure the
python interpreter to look for `__init__` and/or recurse, in order to find the
requested packages.  IF SO, HOW??

```
PyObject* main_module, * global_dict, * expression, *args, *spec;

Py_Initialize ();

char* script = "abc.py";
PySys_SetArgv(1, &script);

//Open the file containing the python modules we want to run
FILE* file_1 = fopen("abc.py", "r");
if (file_1 == 0) fprintf(stdout, "ERROR: File not opened");

//Loads the python file into the interpreter
PyRun_SimpleFile(file_1, "abc.py");

//Creates a python object that contains references to the functions and classes in abc.py 
main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
global_dict = PyModule_GetDict(main_module);

expression = PyDict_GetItemString(global_dict, "view_gui");
spec       = PyObject_CallObject(expression, NULL);

PyObject_CallMethod(spec, "shutdown", NULL);
Py_Finalize();

return NULL;
```

When the python script is invoked from C++, the search seems to
stop when the file `/opt/epd/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib` (or it's
variant, matplotlib.so, etc) are not found.

Note that I can augment the PYTHONPATH to include the exact location of
matplotlib (and other needed packages) to get farther; however, I cannot seem
to include a path to import `matplotlib.cbook`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at (a different version # of) python, I see that `import.c` has the `find_init_module()`, which is a part of the `find_module()`.  Not evident why `find_init_module()` is not executed or fails.